# How to format JSON data response from a view defined by relationships to content types related by entity reference fields

Tags: entities, services, views

I have a content type **event** with content name of the event, event image, a relatioship to **organizer** another relatioship to **participant** and another relationship to self **event** that i call programs. Now I want to make a view which return me a datasource json like

```
{   
    date:"10/10/2017"
    event:[
        {
            img:"image",
            description:"description",
            date:"date complet",
            program:[
                {
                    title:"titre",
                    description:"description",
                    date:"",
                },
                {
                    title:"titre",
                    description:"description",
                    date:"",
                }
            ],
            organizer:[
                {
                    name:"chis",
                    description:"description"
                },
                {
                    name:"chis1",
                    description:"description"
                }
            ],
            participant:[
                {
                    name:"zina lacina",
                    titre:"consultant"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The result is grouping by the date.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) module. It gives you exactly what you need. Just add a view in your view wherever you have 1:n relationships. Setup views for program, organizer and participant and add a contextual filter for the event.

The result will be one event appearing once in your view.